# Whitelist domain name for speedtest.net to allow a test to run

Tags: http, router, domain-name, whitelist

Using a 4G Router (HUAWEI B315) with a domain name whitelist to prevent excessive data usage.

It will only allow our custom API through. 
However when testing the router at new venues it would be great to run speed tests without removing the domain name whitelist everytime.

So this is an example of the current whitelisted domains

```
api.example.com
speedtest.net
```

Running a speed test fails, it simply doesn't connect to a server.
Is it possible to white-list speedtest.net? to allow the speedtest Android App to complete a test?

If not is there another speed test service which could be white-listed easily?

Comment: Probably not. Speedtest.net connects to a variety of volunteer and ISP-hosted servers near individual users. For example, mine hits `http://speedtest.nyroc.rr.com`. There's no way you could whitelist all of these.

Answer (score 1):

Yoiu would not be able to achieve this, as ceejayoz mentions speedtest.net connects to a virtually unlimited number of servers.

What you could do is use something like `fast.com` if you just want to test the download speed (this never leaves the `fast.com` domain), or get a Digital Ocean droplet somewhere and run your own white-listed speed test software (something like https://github.com/adolfintel/speedtest)

Answer (score 0):

- Whitelisting *.MyTest.net works perfectly with the mytest.net Internet speed test because they host their own mirrors and name them dallas.mytest.net, co.mytest.net, fl.mytest.net, etc.
- Every other Internet speed test site I tried to whitelist failed once they attempted to reach their mirrors, (including fast.com mentioned in another post).  I believe this is due to other sites having 3rd parties host their mirrors.
- I tried to whitelist just the FQDNs [www.mytest.net](http://www.mytest.net) and dallas.mytest.net, (their default mirror), and received the error, "ww16.mytest.net took too long to respond", so you may need to experiment a bit with different subdomains if you can't use wildcards in your whitelist.